# Does elementary OS have TRIM enabled? Is my Samsung 8-serie SSD safe?

Tags: updates, kernel, ssd

There was a [kernel bug that made TRIM lose random data](https://blog.algolia.com/when-solid-state-drives-are-not-that-solid/). Samsung submitted a patch to the kernel. Is it applied in elementary OS? Or only new kernel versions? Do I need to update?

How can I find out whether TRIM is used on my system?

Is my 8-serie SSD just blacklisted for TRIM-operations, or does everything work as it's supposed to?

Comment: As far as I know TRIM should be enabled automatically during OS installation if the disk supports it. The Algolia blog reports they use 3.16.0-31 kernel and this series was also present in the first release of Freya (not sure what kernel is in the recent respin). So I *think* you should get the patch in some update sooner or later. What kernel do you actually use? You can find out with a command *uname -a*

Comment: I'm now on work PC but i recall it is 3.19.0-49 now, not sure about 49 part, 4x something anyways. Can I somehow check if TRIM is enabled?

Comment: it seems the easiest way to check if trim is working on your machine is to use the command from here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/464306/a-command-which-checks-that-trim-is-working

Comment: if you have more partitions (e.g. separate /home partition), you can repeat that test for each partition by replacing the "/" with e.g. "/home"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I optimize my SSD with Trim in Freya?](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1199/how-do-i-optimize-my-ssd-with-trim-in-freya)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of that question, that is "How do I TRIM?" This is "Is TRIM Safe?"

Answer (score 2):

from reading the messages on the kernel mailing list I understand that the data loss only is a problem when using the SSD in a raid0 or raid10 configuration.
They have fixed the bug in the kernel, but I can't seem to find in which version the fix was released.

Answer (score -1):

I cannot say much from the theory point of view. My knowledge of the linux kernel is quite limited, but I use elementary Freya since beta with a Samsung 840Pro and have never ever experienced any problems. Cannot guarantee it is safe, but there is at least positive evidence from my example.